# Not able to add bean to the ArrayList

Tags: jsp, servlets, javabeans

I created a JavaBean class like this.

```
package beans;

public class Invoice {
    private String companyName;
    private double price;

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

Then I created a Servlet, in which got the parameters from HTML file, created a Bean. I am trying to add the bean to the ArrayList.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String companyName = request.getParameter("txtCompany");
        double price = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("txtPrice"));

        ArrayList<Invoice> list = (ArrayList<Invoice>) new ArrayList();
        Invoice r = new Invoice();
        r.setCompanyName(companyName);

        list.add(r.getCompanyName());
        r.setPrice(price);

    }

}
```

But I am getting this error on **.add**

```
The method add(Invoice) in the type ArrayList<Invoice> is not applicable for the arguments (String)
```

Where I am might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is badly managed and has mistakes.

1. **Declaration and assignment**. You have `ArrayList<Invoice> list = (ArrayList<Invoice>) new ArrayList();`. While the code will work it is hardly understood *why you don't use generics* during assignment and do your cast. Next, to avoid tight coupling typically we *declare a variable as an interface, but not as a concrete implementation*. Correcting, you'll have the following line: `List<Invoice> list = new ArrayList<Invoice>();`.
2. **Filling the collection**. As you declared you list to contain *only instances of `Invoice` class*, you'll be able to add *only `Invoice` objects and objects that inherit from `Invoice`*. Onviously, with the line `list.add(r.getCompanyName());` you're trying to add a string, which doesn't extend `Invoice`, nor any of its subclasses. So, just add the object: `list.add(r)` and it'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList < Invoice >  list  = ( ArrayList < Invoice >) new ArrayList (); Invoice  r  = new Invoice ();         r . setCompanyName ( companyName );            r . setPrice ( price ); 
list . add (r)} } you should add invoce object only... You are trying to insert string directly...